# hyperplanes in finite vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

how is an hyperplane in a finite vector space?

I know a hyperplane is the kernel of a linear map, and the dimension of the hyperplane is n-1 if dimension of the vector space is n.

So if I have, for example $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$ the vector space of all $(a,b,c)$ such that $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}_2$... how is an hyperplane here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A hyperplane in *any* vector space V is a subspace W such that V/W is one dimensional.

This is equivalent to defining them as kernels of linear maps into the base field.

It has nothing to do with the field or dimensionality whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

I find it illustrative to think in terms of subspaces. If your space has dimension $n$, just pick any $n - 1$ linearly independent vectors. Their span is a subspace of codimension $1$ (dimenions $n - 1$).

The hyperplanes, then, are just translations of these proper maximal subspaces; their cosets.

In your specific example, here are two rough drawings of a maximal proper subspace and one of its translates, both hyperplanes:
[image]

But don't be fooled; the $8$ points are all there is in $\Bbb Z_2^3$; the lines are just there to help us see the points as $\{0,1\}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the span $\lbrace (1,0,0),(0,1,0) \rbrace$. It is a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbf{Z_{2}}^{3}$ and is the kernel of the functional $T: \mathbf{Z_{2}}^{3} \to \mathbf{Z_{2}}, (a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}) \to a_{3}$